# DECODE Statement to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a nested `DECODE` statement that I am trying to rewrite from Oracle to SQL Server and it is giving me fits.  Can anyone please help me to rewrite this line:

```
DECODE(UR.UR_REG_IND, 'P', 'P', 'Y') = DECODE(:UR_REG_IND, 'B', DECODE(UR.UR_REG_IND, 'P', 'P', 'Y'), :UR_REG_IND)
```

I understand the `:UR_REG_IND` is an input variable `@UR_REG_IND` and I also understand the `DECODE` is a type of `CASE` in SQL, but I am having all kinds of trouble trying to rewrite this without a nested `CASE` statement, if its even possible.

Comment: `DECODE` is a function, yet in your example you seem to be assigning to it, which I believe is incorrect (though I'm not a PL/SQL user, so I don't know for certain).

Comment: what is *the intent* of the code? I'm trying to follow what's supposed to happen, but it looks like the logic is "return 'P' if the value is 'P' otherwise return the value" - which is useless code.

Comment: It looks like you have a nested DECODE here so why are you trying to avoid nested case expressions? Perhaps if you could verbalize what you are trying to do with the code we can help you find a good approach to this in t-sql.

Comment: @Dai: it's not an assignment, it's a comparison. In PL/SQL the assignment operator is `:=`

Comment: The intent of the code is to return a 'P' if P is selected, a 'Y' if Y is selected and both if 'B' is selected.  Yes, the DECODE is nested but it is part of a much larger query.  I didn't write the code, just trying to rewrite it in SQL from Oracle...

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines. The parentheses are not needed but they may help readability.

```
case ur.ur_reg_ind when 'P' then 'P' else 'Y' end =
case :ur_reg_ind   when 'B' then (case  ur.ur.reg_ind when 'P' then 'P' else 'Y' end)
                   else     :ur_reg_ind end
```

Note that this translation should work equally well in Oracle itself - it is actually how I would write that condition. It is longer, perhaps, but to me it seems much easier to read and understand (and therefore to maintain).

Comment: I copied this into my larger query and its giving me syntax errors with the inner most case... Expecting '(', or SELECT, and the = sign in the first case after end...Incorrect syntax after '='.  This is the same problem I had trying to nest it myself.  Here is what I have above and below it:UP.UP_EFF_DATE BETWEEN :FROM_DATE AND :THRU_DATE AND 
   UR.UR_REG_IND =     
    case ur.ur_reg_ind 
     when 'P' then 'P' else 'Y' end =
      case :ur_reg_ind   when 'B' then (case  ur.ur.reg_ind when 'P' then 'P' else 'Y' end)
                   else     :ur_reg_ind end
   UP.UW_CODE <> 1000 AND

Comment: @Levi - That makes no sense and it wouldn't work with either CASE or DECODE in Oracle either, because you have the condition `and UR.UR_REG_IND = <something> = <yet_another_thing>`. You can't have two comparisons in a row like that in a condition in any SQL flavor. What do you really **mean** there - do you need all three "things" to be equal?

Comment: Again, please be patient with me, I didn't write it nor have I edited any of it.  It doesn't make sense to me either, hence I am here.  This is the original code...AND UP.UP_EFF_DATE BETWEEN :FROM_DATE AND :THRU_DATE'

        '   AND DECODE(UR.UR_REG_IND, '#39'P'#39', '#39'P'#39', '#39'Y'#39') = DECODE(:UR_REG_IND' +
        ', '#39'B'#39', DECODE(UR.UR_REG_IND, '#39'P'#39', '#39'P'#39', '#39'Y'#39'), :UR_REG_IND) '
      '   AND UP.UW_CODE      <> 1000'